# Running Vaadin in Eclipse+Tomcat appends full class path to .java file, which throws 404

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, vaadin

While I have plenty of experience with Eclipse, I am very new to Vaadin. I'm having a simple issue when running my project. By default the project runs as...

```
http://localhost:8080/Sample_App/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/sample/Sample_Application.java
```

...which throws a 404 error, forcing me to manually adjust it every time I run. Instead I obviously want it to run as...

```
http://localhost:8080/Sample_App
```

How do I go about adjusting this? (I tried the proposed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570418/how-to-prevent-eclipsetomcat-from-running-current-class-instead-of-project-vaa?rq=1) which isn't working for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost stupid how simple the answer was.

When running the project, instead of highlighting the class file in the Project Explorer, highlight the very base of the project before running. This is what we want to run anyway, not the class file itself.

Comment: what do you mean by highlighting "the very base of the project " ? i got the same problem on my project and i don't know how to fix